# T4 Text Templating

Tags: c#, t4, texttemplate

I have the following .tt file that I wish to use as an include file where I want to expose some properties to the main T4 files:

**Include.tt**

```
<#@ assembly name="$(ProjectDir)bin\Debug\EPPlus.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Configuration.dll" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Configuration" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" #>
<#@ import namespace="OfficeOpenXml" #>
<#
    public static string EDIInputPath
    {
        get
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["inputPath"];
        }
    }
#>
```

When saving this code it throws 7 compile time errors with the first one saying "Statement expected".

I don't use T4 templates very often so I am not entirely sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: You may already be doing this but if you are not using Tangible T4 or some other extension to make t4 more readable then definitely grab it! http://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com/T4-Editor-Visual-T4-Editing.html it makes working with them so much easier. You can also right click the TT file and "Debug Template"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to see what is going wrong is to change the CustomTool property on the T4 file to be **TextTemplatingFilePreprocessor**. Then you can see the generated code inside Visual Studio.

In your case the problem is that inside the standard control block

```
<# #>
```

you can only have statements that would work inside a method. The T4 template engine will put these statements inside a TransformText() method that outputs the text for the template.

You have defined a property which is not allowed inside a method. Your property code needs to go into a class feature block:

```
<#+ #>
```